# implicitwait and explicitwait not solving the issue in Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been testing an application involving multiple ajax calls, so I required wait condition so that elements are present/visible once the ajax call is made. I used both methods `implicitwait` and `explicitwait` but none of them seem to be working for me as one or the other exceptions are generated as follows:

1.Unable to locate element

2.Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions

Implicit wait used as follows:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

PROBLEM:
When I test this code, after browser opens, it throws exception in 2 seconds.

> Result:Exception generated

Explicit Wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, /*seconds=*/3); 
WebElement element = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("q"));
```

PROBLEM:

When I test this code, after browser opens, it throws exception in 2 seconds

> Result:Exception generated.

Also used visibilityOfElementLocated but it does not work for me.

---

Has anybody faced this issue or anybody has a solution for this??

Comment: Can you please increase the time value in ExplicitWait?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I have faced that issue before but I also wrote my own custom DOM polling class.  Here's what I do.

```
private int Timer = 180;

private bool CheckForElement(WebDriver driver,string byType,string selector)
{
  bool elementFound = false;

  for (int i = Timer - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
       if (!itemFound)
       {
          Thread.Sleep(1000); //sets the loop to check every second this can be done at a much faster or slower rate depending on your preferences
          if (byType.ToLower() == "id")
          {
           try{
               WebDriver element = driver.FindElement(By.Id(selector);
               if(element.Displayed)
               {
                   elementFound = true;
               }
           }
           catch {
               //Do Nothing Here as we don't need to handle the exception
           }
          }
          else if (byType.ToLower() == "tagname")
          {
           try{
               WebDriver element = driver.FindElement(By.TagName(selector);
               if(element.Displayed)
               {
                   elementFound = true;
               }
           }
           catch {
               //Do Nothing Here as we don't need to handle the exception
           }
          }
          else if (byType.ToLower() == "cssselector")
          {
           try{
               WebDriver element = driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector(selector);
               if(element.Displayed)
               {
                   elementFound = true;
               }
           }
           catch {
               //Do Nothing Here as we don't need to handle the exception
           }
          }
          else if (byType.ToLower() == "classname")
          {
           try{
               WebDriver element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(selector);
               if(element.Displayed)
               {
                   elementFound = true;
               }
           }
           catch {
               //Do Nothing Here as we don't need to handle the exception
           }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          i = 0; //stops the loop when the element is found
      }
   }

  return elementFound ;
}
```